# Apply tags based on variables in text widget

Tags: python, tkinter, tags

I am trying to color the `temp` variable, but with no luck:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
temp='Hello'
text.insert(INSERT, "Hello %s" %temp)
text.pack()
x=1
y=10
text.tag_add("tag1", "1.4", "@%d,%d" %(x, y))
text.tag_config("tag1", background="blue", foreground="yellow")
root.mainloop()
```

And besides the way to do it if there's any, is there a way to specify the indices using variables `x` and `y`? I think that could solve my problem.

*Python 2.7 - Windows*

Comment: Are you aware that the `@` causes the numbers to be treated as pixels?

Comment: I didn't know what `@` does. Sorry. But I found a solution to get the indices using variables, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I could do this to set the indexes using variables.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text = Text(root)
temp='Hello'
text.insert(INSERT, "Hello %s" %temp)
text.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

text.tag_configure("BOLD", foreground='green')
def get_start():
    x=1
    y=1
    return '%d.%d' %(x,y)
def get_end():
    x=1
    y=7
    return '%d.%d' %(x,y) 
def test():
    text.tag_add("BOLD", get_start(), get_end())

bold_btn = Button(root, text="Bold", command=test)
bold_btn.pack(side="left")


root.mainloop()
```